# How to convert a vector into a matrix ? (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have a vector with the size (1,9) with the value as follows:

```
 V= [0.5 0.1 0.1 0.9 0.5 0.1 0.9 0.9 0.5]
```

How can I convert the vector `V` into the matrix `M` with the size of (3,3) which the first row is the first 3 elements of the vector and the second row contains the next 3 elements of the vector and keeping that rule for all of other elements of the vector as follows:

```
       0.5 0.1 0.1
M=     0.9 0.5 0.1
       0.9 0.9 0.5
```

Also for different sized vectors, like for example (1,100), how can I convert into a matrix of (10,10) base on the rule above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html), then transpose the result:

```
M = reshape(V, 3, 3).';
```

`reshape` transforms a vector into a matrix of a desired size.  The matrix is created in **column-major** order.  Therefore, just using `reshape` by itself will place the elements in the columns.  Since you desire the elements to be populated by rows, a trick is to simply transpose the result.

In general, you want to reshape a `N` element vector `V` into a square matrix `M` of size `sqrt(N) x sqrt(N)` in row-major order.  You can do this for the general case:

```
N = sqrt(numel(V));
M = reshape(V, N, N).';
```

This of course assumes that the total number of elements in `V` is a perfect square.